# Quit scrambling my keyboard!

Tags: cipher

It happened to me again! More scrambled, this time.

```
ncb , r2u 3b,99 bn/c b72b ic326c
```

> Still a US Keyboard, but this time, it's not across the keys...

Comment: Is 3b,99 supposed to be 3b,00?

Comment: You might want to be careful with the creation of this type of puzzle. By using frequency analysis it is very easy to spot the pattern

Comment: @Avi yes, i did this by hand, and humans aren't perfect

Comment: @Adam Yes, I understand, because this is a keyboard cipher. This keyboard cipher is also a ceaser cipher with a scrambled alphabet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original text is:

> ncb , r2u 3b,99 bn/c b72b ic326c

The encoded text is:

> Yet I can stikk type that mesage

The mapping is:

> zxcvbnm,./ to qwertyuiop
>  wertyuiop to zxcvbnm,./
>  234567890 to asdfghjkl

With some minor typos, the intended message is probably something like:

> **Yet I can still type this message**

Comment: Correct. But although i'm sure the mapping is correct, that's not what I intended.
(The steps i used was, since the keyboard keys are in rows that are slanted, you go to the bottom of a row and then to the top of the next, so 1qaz2wsx3edc4rfv5tgb6yhn7ujm8ik,9ol.0p;/ is the order of the keyboard, so just do +2 ceaser cipher) Good job?